# Google Analytics Data API - Get total events

Tags: api, events, google-analytics

I would like to receive the total events from the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed#dataRequest). I already authorized the access to GA through OAuth2 but I don't understand the query I need to send.

This is how I'm tracking the event in my website:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "Downloads", "App", "Windows","1"]);" href="#download">
```

This is what I have so far but it's not returning the total events:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?start-date=2010-06-01&end-date=2013-07-01&dimensions=ga:day,ga:visitorType&metrics=ga:visits&sort=ga:day&ga:totalEvents&ga:uniqueEvents&dimensions=ga:eventAction&dimensions=ga:eventCategory&max-results=20&ids=ga:1234567
```

How can I receive the total events?
Would be someone so nice to show me an exmaple string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Google API Explorer to form your query. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.ga.get